# Is it possible to "restore" an itunes iphone backup to an ipad?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, backup

Is it possible to "restore" an iphone backup to an ipad, or an ipod touch?

Obviously there are iphone specific apps etc. but can you get most of your data (like passwords f.ex.) into an ipad/ipod touch from an itunes backup of an iphone?

Comment: Just don't forget you can't restore to a device that only supports an older iOS version. So you can't restore an iPhone 6 backup to an original iPad, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the backups are interchangeable between device types.

Comment: For reference, this is currently documented [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204136) (see the "Can I use my device's backup for another kind of device, such as an iPhone backup for an iPad?" section).

Answer (score 0):

I just did it right now and was **very** disappointed the restore from iPhone backup only partially covered the data in the backup. You can pretty much sync `Notes`, `Calendar`, and `Messages` and also find a placeholder stub of all apps installed on your iPhone that will all have the download cloud down arrow icon present on their tiles in the Home Screen. What is conspicuously missing (and I have no idea why they would even omit this) is the `Photos` app's images and videos. Also missing is local `Files` saved on the iPhone. There's probably other omissions I haven't yet figured out.

This was one of the major reasons why I even bothered buying an iPad to have a scratch pad surface to restore deleted photos off my iPhone that could be restored from a backup. Now I have to use a scratch iPhone device to retrieve these images which got botched in an AirDrop transfer. Either that or backup locally to another PC, restore the old backup from this PC and overwrite my iPhone and hope I can retrieve those deleted photos in a safe way and then overwrite my iPhone again with the new backup. All this could be avoided if iTunes could do selective restores rather than the whole all or nothing solution it currently offers. It would be awesome [to just be able to restore photos](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6838209), or messages, or notes or whatever subset from the backup you wish to restore and merge into a given device.

When you go to attempt a restore from an iPhone backup iTunes will prompt you with the following dialog

> Restore from Backup
>
> Chose a backup to restore. This will restore only the contacts, calendars, notes, and settings, not the iPad firmware.
>
> iPad Name [pull down list of backups on the PC]
>
> Last Backed Up. MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM
>
> [Restore] [Cancel]

You may also see

> iTunes
>
> Settings and data from some apps are not compatible with iPad and will not be restored.
>
> [Continue] [Cancel]

It would be great to actually have that determination made explicit so you can see what data and apps are specifically going to be omitted from the restore operation. Which apps and data specifically are compatible/not compatible.

Comment: dang, another caveat in this restore to another device problem is you need enough disk space on the secondary device otherwise you get stuck with: `iTunes could not restore the iPhone "iphoneIDXXX" because not enough free space is available on the iPhone.` That would be another reason why it would be great to pick and choose what I want to restore rather than all or none.